# Не могу понять формулировку задания

Tags: python

Есть N целых чисел. Сами числа нам неизвестны, но известно, что никакие два из этих чисел не имеют одинакового остатка при делении на N. Требуется подсчитать остаток от деления их суммы на N.

Это нужно написать на python, я понимаю как это должно выглядеть, но не могу понять формулировку "Сами числа нам неизвестны, но известно, что никакие два из этих чисел не имеют одинакового остатка при делении на N"

Пожалуйста объясните ее....

Comment: это означает что у всех чисел разные отстатки от деления на N. Одинаковых остатков нет.

Comment: решается одной строчкой кода, кстати.

Comment: насчет одной строчки я понимаю, просто запутался с формулировкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не всегда нужно решать задачу в лоб, иногда нужно просто *взять листик бумаги и ручку* и записать несколько вариантов - очень действенный метод.

Что касается задачи то очень важно тут понимать что такое остаток от деления. Остаток от деления никогда не превосходит делитель.
Это обозначает остатки будут представлены от 0 до N-1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И уже исходя из этого можно сделать предположение как это посчитать. В частности есть в математике знаменитая формула Гаусса, ее можно взять за основу. Надеюсь мои мысли и мой набросок приблизит Вас к цели.